# Can't edit Google Smart Home Action sample invocation

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I want to edit the sample invocations showed in the actions directory, but I can't find the Sample Invocations section in my Directory Information section.
I can find only short description and full description.
But in the action directory, under the title: "ASK YOUR ASSISTANT" there are a lot of sample invocations and not all of them are relevant.
How can I edit them?

Comment: Hi, when you click on Directory Information - below "Description" there should be a box with "Sample Invocations". Do you have that?

Comment: This is the problem, there is no such section..

Comment: Hm, you are using Smart Home? It's possible this exists for only some Actions but maybe not for Smart Home. I would suggest contacting public support at the form on this site: https://developers.google.com/actions/support/

Comment: For smart home, these invocations are defined based on the traits your devices support. Please file an issue with more detail about the types/traits you are using and the invocations that are not relevant for your device: https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/support

Answer (score 0):

Invocation is associated with a display name that represents a brand, name, or persona that lets users ask Assistant to invoke your Actions. With assistant actions you can define your own invocations but for Smart Home the sample invocations are defined based on the traits your device supports and are defined by Google.

For example, you can say the following phrases to invoke three separate Actions in an project with a display name of "Facts about Google":

- "Ok Google, talk to Facts about Google"
- "Ok Google, talk to Facts about Google to get company facts"
- "Ok Google, talk to Facts about Google to get history facts"